# Regex {number..number} usage in PowerShell like Bash

Tags: regex, bash, powershell

I am using this code in Bash:

```
cp -r fromsourcefolder/{150..300} ./todestinationfolder
```

How can I write this command in PowerShell or any other method to do that in Windows?

Note:I have many folders in numeric order like `1,2, ... ,1000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(150..300) | foreach {Copy-Item C:\source\$_ C:\destination -Recurse}
```

Comment: This works for copy but all copied files overwrite in a folder. I need to keep the file order.  I think some changes in C:\destination are required. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what do you mean by file order?

Comment: I mean to copy under the same file name. For ex., I tried the code with file names 0.0002 and 0.0003. (0.0002..0.0003) | foreach... I found copied files in the 0 folder. I need to find 0.0002/* and 0.0003/*.

Comment: Ok. I figured out the problem.

Comment: You are right. This problem is due to the decimal number. I changed the code (2..3) | foreach {Copy-Item C:\source\0.000$_ C:\destination -Recurse}